# Android Register a file for download

Tags: android, file, android-intent, gmail, registration

A core part of my app is a nonstandard file type, in my case .crumb
The intent works properly for almost everything, except in the Gmail app.
I have confirmed that this intent works from file browsers, the Hotmail app, Skype, the aosp email app, etc.
But Gmail alone doesn't give the option to download.

Is there some kind of other file registration I'm supposed to do? Here is my intent filter:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="100">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.crumb" />
            <data android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: removing the scheme from this makes the intent work in gmail, but it also shows up all over the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this intent but it don't work directly with skype. Skype save the file in download directory then, file can be downloaded with a file browser...

The solution for gmail is adding this second intent - filter (scheme is removing) :

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.crumb" />   
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
```